# Can I create function using 'function' class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know, just for fun, if I can create functions using *function* class constructor, i.e. without language construct *def*, just like creating class by instantiating type object. I know, function constructor takes 2 args - code object and globals. But I don't know how I should **compile** the source properly.

```
>>> def f(): 
...     pass

>>> Function = type(f) 
>>> Function
<class 'function'>
>>> code = compile("x + 10", "<string>", "exec")
>>> f = Function(code, globals())
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> f(20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <module>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Note that it can take more than just 2 arguments.  `function(code, globals[, name[, argdefs[, closure]]])`

Comment: Can you explane more? Where can I read about it?

Comment: `import types; help(types.FunctionType)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set many attributes on the code object, such as co_varnames, co_nlocals, etc.
What clearly works is

```
code = compile("def foo(n):return n+10", "<string>", "exec").co_consts[0]
func = Function(code, globals())
```

but I guess this would be considered cheating. To really define the code object from scratch, do (for 3.3)

```
code = types.CodeType(1, 0, 1, 2, 67, b'|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x17S', (None, 10), 
                      (), ('x',), '<string>', 'f', 1, b'\x00\x01')
func = Function(code, globals())
print(func(10))
```

This, of course, requires you to do the entire compile() yourself.

Comment: Is that because `compile` only returns objects with `co_argcount == 0`?

Comment: @Tinctorius: indeed. The compiler gives an argcount only when it enters a scope, which requires it have a list of parameter names (and surrounding scopes). compile() just provides no way of passing that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this works:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> def f(): pass
... 
>>> func = type(f)
>>> code = compile("global x\nx += 10","<string>","exec")
>>> nf = func(code,globals())
>>> nf()
>>> x
10
```

Don't know how you'd pass arguments to the function though.

Comment: Globals are never the solution.

Comment: This is about as far as I've gotten as well.  Can't seem to put a `return` in the code either as it gives a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @Tinctorius: yeah, hence the statement about passing arguments. But the question was "can one create functions using function class constructor?"... and the example shows just that.

Comment: @isedev: no, the question was "how should I compile the code properly"? The OP answered the literal question (how to create function objects) in his post already, pointing out that the resulting function wasn't really proper.